# Whether this is a set cover

Tags: np-hard, set-cover

Assume that the universe is U, and the subfamily is S={s11,s12,...s1a,s21,...,s2b,...,sn1,...snz}, each element is the subset of U. Now I want choose the minimal number of elements in S to cover the universe, but NOTE that if s11 is selected, {s12,...s1a} will not be considered,  this is the same to all the element in {s11,s12,...s1a,s21,...,s2b,...,sn1,...snz}. 
I know it is total a set cover problem, but I am not sure now with my constraint satisfied. Whether it is still a set cover problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I use 'a'....'z', it does not mean that n=z, it is just a symbol. I don't know how to edit equation in stackoverflow. In fact subfamily is known to me.

Comment: You would probably have better responses on programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: It is not a programmer problem, just an analysis.

Comment: Yes but this stack is not for such questions. Another good one might be math.stackexchange.com